# AWS EC2 SSH Login Keeps Failing - Permission Denied (Public Key)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

This is really starting to bug me now. I'm working (testing) on a new project in AWS EC2, I can successfully create a LAMP stack and get FTP working as long as other processes I'm playing with, I always seem to get myself locked out of the server? I.e. when I try to SSH back in, I get permission denied (public key). This has happened about 4/5 times now.

The private key on my machine is chmod 400 and never changes. The ftp server is still working, and other services are still working, but I still can't get access.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

```
Glenns-MacBook-Pro:~ deepgc$ ssh -i /Users/deepgc/Dropbox/ft247\ management/Hosting/AWS/247HouseRadio.pem ec2-user@54.191.212.253 -v
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 54.191.212.253 [54.191.212.253] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/deepgc/Dropbox/ft247 management/Hosting/AWS/247HouseRadio.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/deepgc/Dropbox/ft247 management/Hosting/AWS/247HouseRadio.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 6d:d7:d6:26:3b:11:3e:95:a9:c7:74:b5:1c:81:64:e1
debug1: Host '54.191.212.253' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/deepgc/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/deepgc/Dropbox/ft247 management/Hosting/AWS/247HouseRadio.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: post the output of the login with `-v` flagged. in other words, `ssh user@host -v`.

Comment: Glenn- you can edit your original question to add those. I'll try to read through it as well. What's the name of the ssh key that SHOULD work?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the key, as it works for other instances. Is it possible for linux to lock the account if some folders have had their permissions set to 777?

Comment: if your `~/.ssh` folder, or your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the EC2 instance has the wrong permissions, it won't accept the keys.

Comment: That is starting to make sense. Where are these files stored so I know not to disrupt them in the future?

Comment: I've found it, it's obviously a hidden folder. So if I were to change the permissions of the folder ec2-user (in the home directory), that would lock out the keys